# Add Xml Node and Save it from string content of xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I got the string from xml file.now i want to Add the new node in that.How can i do?The code is like this.

```
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(webResource.Attributes["content"].ToString());
string resourceContent = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(binary);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(resourceContent);
```

Here in resourceContent i got the string from xml file now how can i add new node in that ..The Xml file is like this..

```
<root name="account">  

<node cId="7143cd70-cd0e-e211-b10a-984be173a3b0" cName="Variety Store (sample)" pId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" pName="" />

</root>
```

More clarification=i got the whole XML in String right?now i want just add one node and save back to XML file...but Be remember that i can just save the content of xml file..i dont have rights to paste the whole xml into specify path

Comment: I'm now voting you down because you've received two answers to this question which are correct according to the question asked, but your follow up comments to those suggest you've asked the wrong question or that actually this is impossible to answer because you won't accept answers given.  [deep breath] so to my mind this looks like a huge waste of my time and anybody else's.

Comment: @Andras:This is not wasting any time..but my requirement is some what complicated...you voting this down its ok whatever you want you can do..but still i didnt get my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(resourceContent);
xDoc.Add(new XElement("name", "new content"));
```

Comment: How can we save it in xml file

Comment: use the save method of xdocument http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save.aspx

Comment: i want to add node under root

Comment: More clarification=i got the whole XML in String right?now i want just add one node and save back to XML file...but Be remember that i can just save the content of xml file..i dont have rights to paste the whole xml into specify path